# Changing index in Neo4j affects the search in cypher

Tags: lucene, neo4j, cypher

I am using Neo4j 2.0 .

I have a label `PROD`. All nodes having label `PROD` have a property `name`. I have created an index on `name` like this :

```
CREATE INDEX ON :PROD(name)
```

After creating an index if I change value of the property `name` from "old" to "new", the following query works fine in a small dataset used for testing but not in our production data with 700 nodes having label `PROD` (where totally there are around a million nodes with other labels).

```
MATCH (n:PROD) WHERE n.name="new" RETURN n;
```

I have also created legacy index on the same field and  after dropping and re-indexing the node on modification, it works perfectly fine on both test and production datasets.

Is there a way to ensure the indices are updated? What am I doing wrong? Why does the above query fail for large dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:schema` command in Neo4j browser or `schema` in neo4j-shell. The output should indicate which indexes have been created and which of them are already online.

Additionally there's a [programmatic way to wait until index population has finished](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.1.3/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/schema/Schema.html#awaitIndexesOnline(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).

Consider upgrading to 2.1.3, indexing has improved since 2.0.